# Where in the attic is this ceiling leak coming from?

Tags: hvac, leak, ceiling

There are couple of circular spots on the ceiling that are growing slowly and directly on top in the attic are these big metal-like boxes that ducts connect to. I'm not sure what they are. One of these sits directly on top of where the 'leaks' are, so I don't know what's causing the marks and whether it's an easy fix or not. Thanks!

[image]

[image].

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture but they look like air ducts.  If that’s true and they carry air conditioning then, where warm moist attic air meets cold vent the result is condensation.  The solution is insulation.  I hate to point it out, but your investigation may have made the problem worse as you’ve shifted loose fill insulation around to see what is happening.

Comment: Also, leaks from above a duct or rafter will often travel along the bottom to drip from a location a meter or more away. The water can also travel a considerable distance under roofing material until coming through the roof. It may be best to replace roofing and flashing.